# Transfer data from Azure SQL VM to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Is there any fast way to transfer a large amount of data stored in a SQL database that is hosted on an Azure VM to Azure SQL database?

Regards

Comment: Did you copy/paste your post title into Google and read the results on the first page?

Comment: you have to provide more information

Answer (score 1):

Please try [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql). Perform an assessment of the database with that tool before transfer the data. It is not only fast but also very user-friendly. Download the tool from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).